# How can I prevent two or more users with different IPs from connecting to my server simultaneously using one username?

Tags: server, ssh, adduser

One of the methods I use to bypass internet filtering/censorship in my country is SSH tunneling. To do this, I create a user on an Ubuntu 18.04 server using the command `adduser USERNAME --shell=/bin/false`. However, there is a major flaw in this method, which is that multiple users with different IP addresses can simultaneously connect to my server using this username, causing the server's IP to be filtered by the government. How can I prevent two or more users with different IPs from connecting (SSH tunneling) to my server simultaneously using one username?

P.s. I am a beginner Linux and Ubuntu user, so please explain all the steps in a simple way.

Comment: Damn! Are you connecting from North Korea?  If the actual usage is tunneling why don't use `wireguard` instead?

Comment: Couldn't you just do something like set up SSH keys and then, you know, not give the keys to anyone else?

Comment: @KGIII I am new to Linux servers. Could you please explain it as an answer in a simple way or at least provide a link for me to read about it myself?

Comment: It's not really an answer to your question, it's something else entirely. Otherwise, I'd happily make it an answer. You can read [this link] to learn how to do this. I don't actually have an answer for your specific question. It's just another option.

Comment: @KGIII Thank you for your comment, but it seems like you forgot to include the link.

Comment: Oops! [Link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/ssh-with-key)! It's not terribly difficult and those are good directions. If you do go that route and have problems, you can ask another question specific to that process (assuming you can't find the answer yourself).

Comment: Beside using ssh keys, [as mentioned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/406264/209677) I'd go with a `AlowUsers` directive on `sshd_config` (test with [sshd test mode](https://superuser.com/a/1291078/500826)), or a firewall ([ufw](https://launchpad.net/ufw)/nftables/iptables) for a more general way (extendable to any port/service). Avoid using TCP wrappers, and if I understand you correctly, setting a maximum number of login sessions is *not* what you want and have some risks

Comment: @PabloBianchi Assuming that I create a user named "johndoe" on my server and provide him with the password, server IP, and port so that he can bypass filtering through it; however, if these credentials are given to someone else, they cannot use this account simultaneously with two different IP addresses. How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, on server, [add](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490120/209677) `AllowUsers johndoe@johnWanIP` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`. You would need extra magic to have johnWanIP1 XOR johnWanIP2.

Answer (score 7):

A simple method to prevent simultaneous connections from multiple IPs would be to limit the number of active sessions a user can have open. This can be done by creating a single file and restarting the SSH daemon.

Here's how you can do it:

0. Connect to your server (if not already connected)
1. Create a file in `/etc/security/limits.d` to contain the connection limit rule:

   ```
   sudo {editor of choice} /etc/security/limits.d/10-ssh.conf
   ```

   <sup>**Note:** Be sure to replace `{editor of choice}` with your preferred text editor.</sup>
2. Paste or type the following into the new file:

   ```
   # Additional limits for users of SSH
   *    hard    maxlogins   1
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Restart the SSH daemon

   ```
   sudo service ssh restart
   ```

#### How the configuration works

| Item | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| `*` | Who the rule applies to |
| `hard` | What level of enforcement should be used |
| `maxlogins` | What is being enforced |
| `1` | The limit to enforce |

If you would like only certain users to have limits, you can replace `*` with a specific user name. For example:

```
johnny   hard   maxlogins   3
```

This will limit *just* the `johnny` account to three simultaneous sessions.

If you would like certain user groups to have limits, you can replace `*` with a group name. For example:

```
@family   hard   maxlogins   1
```

This will limit accounts in the `family` group to one simultaneous connection.

If you would like multiple levels, you can add more lines to the file. For example:

```
# Additional limits for users of SSH
@family   hard   maxlogins   1
johnny    hard   maxlogins   2
*         hard   maxlogins   3
```

If you decide to remove the limits in the future, simply delete the file or rename it to something like `10-ssh.old` and restart the SSH daemon.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didn't work. I created two configurations with the same username and password on two mobile phones with two different IP addresses. Then I exactly followed the solution you suggested, but both phones were able to connect to my server simultaneously.

Answer (score 4):

On Ubuntu `pam_limits` can limit the number of sessions per user.

While you read the configuration files of Ubuntu from `/etc/pam.d/login` for example you can find a line something like `session require pam_limits.so`.

```
# Sets up user limits according to /etc/security/limits.conf
# (Replaces the use of /etc/limits in old login)
session require pam_limits.so
```

So, the path for configuration files for limits has been changed comparing to older versions of `login`.

Anyway it goes to `/etc/security/` location same as in the [previous answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1465131/754937) by @matigo however I would edit `limits.conf` file instead of creating files in subfolders since it's only one user you need limit.

In order to limit the number of sessions per user, you can add entries to a file in `/etc/security/limits.conf`

*Actually you see examples in the comments in this file*

Add a line by the end of file:

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
johndoe         hard    maxlogins      1
```

Bear in mind to **logout your user `johndoe`** and **restart `sshd`** after your edits to apply.

```
pkill -9 -u johndoe # kill all running apps under johndoe user
service ssh restart
```

To kill exactly `johndoe` terminal sessions

```
# First run "w" command

[root@vps ~]# w
00:34:21 up 48 days, 23:38, 4 users, load average: 0.79, 0.58, 0.56
USER TTY FROM LOGIN@ IDLE JCPU PCPU WHAT
kate pts/0 192.168.1.101 19:47 4:45m 0.04s 0.00s mc
johndoe pts/1 192.168.1.102 20:35 3:54m 2:23 0.00s nano
max pts/2 192.168.1.103 00:27 5.00s 0.08s 0.04s top
root pts/4 192.168.1.104 00:34 1.00s 0.02s 0.01s w

# then use pkill
pkill -9 -t pts/1

# then restart SSH
service ssh restart
```

P.S. I didn't tested, but maybe you would need *"-"* instead of *"hard"* in a limit type column.

```
#<domain>      <type>  <item>         <value>
johndoe         -       maxlogins      1
```

That should be a solution in case you stick with a direct SSH connection... but if you use it for tunneling why just don't use something like `wireguard`?

**EDIT 2023-05-02**

While you use SSH tunneling I believe you need some workaround.
Stream connections are not visible with `w` command, but you can reveal them with `netstat`.

So my guess is to use `~/.ssh/rc` to see and count your running connections in case `johndoe  -  maxlogins  1` in `limits.conf` not working.

First check `PermitUserRC` option in `sshd_config`. You need to enable it (by default it's enabled) and restart `ssh` service.

Then use a script to check amount of connections from current IP. Here is a draft script to use (add these lines into your `~/.ssh/rc` under user `johndoe`):

```
myip=`awk -F" " '{split($0,a); print a[1]}' <<< $SSH_CLIENT`
conncount=`netstat -anpW | grep ':22 \+' | grep ESTABLISHED | grep $myip | wc -l`
if test $conncount -gt 1; then exit 429; fi;
```

Explanation: Line (1) Get your current IP, (2) Count amount of connections to `:22` port from `$myip` and (3) if we have greater than 1 connection from this our IP terminate process and exit with error code `429`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work! I created two configurations with the same username and password on two mobile phones with two different IP addresses. Then I edited file `/etc/security/limits.conf` and added `johndoe   -   maxlogins    1` (see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zV7J5.png)), but both phones were able to connect to my server simultaneously! I tried `johndoe   hard   maxlogins    1`, too. I want this for ssh tunneling. The `WireGuard` protocol does not work with many ISPs in Iran.

Comment: @vahid `johndoe   -   maxlogins    1` should work. Anyway you use SSH tunneling, so the connection won't show up in `w` output. It means this is a nologin system user so `maxlogins` in `limits.conf` is not useful and same as `MaxSessions` in `sshd_config` has no effect on port forwarding.
You connect over SOCKS proxy, which is tied to a web browser, which usually opens multiple streams at once with `nologin`.
You can `listen 10022` in `sshd_config` and use this `10022` port in your SOCKS connection without limits if it works for you.. However I could not to find an option to limit nologin.

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan I guess you should dig to the `PermitUserRC` in `sshd_config`. You need to enable it (by default it's enabled). Then add some script wrapper into `~/.ssh/rc`

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan how do you connect your phone(s)?

Comment: I connect the phones by apps like [Matsuri](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=moe.matsuri.lite) and then in +icon->Manual Settings->SSH and then I write the server's Ip, port, username, and password (please see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojIMY.jpg)).

Comment: @VahidDamanafshan Updated an answer

Comment: Thank you for your "Edit", but as I said in my question, I am completely a beginner Linux and Ubuntu user, so please explain your new solution in a simple way.